# Integrate and NIntegrate disagreeing over branch cut of Sqrt?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, bugs, numerics, complex

**Bug introduced after 8.0.4 and before 9.0.1, and fixed in 11.1.0.**

---

In *Mathematica 10.2* I'm trying to integrate this piecewise continuous function, but `Integrate` and `NIntegrate` seem to disagree on the branch cut of `Sqrt[]`:

```
 Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, 0, Pi}]
 (* 2 Sqrt[2] - I Pi *)

 NIntegrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, 0, Pi}]
 (* 1.06568 - 4.51028*10^-16 I *)
```

It seems that `NIntegrate`'s answer is correct if `Sqrt[]` has its branch cut on the negative real axis. Is there a way to force `Integrate` to use the same branch cut?

Comment: Same result in v9.0.1 and v10.4.1, but `1/2 (4 Sqrt[2] + Log[17 - 12 Sqrt[2]])` in v8.0.4, which is correct. I think it's safe to say it's a bug.

Comment: 5.2 gives consistent results, tho.

Comment: @J.M. You mean v5.2 is consistent with v9 and v10? So the bug was once fixed but now reintroduced :D?

Comment: @xzczd, I mean, 5.2 yields (after simplification) `2 (Sqrt[2] - ArcSinh[1])`. So, something went wrong in between 5.2 and 9.

Comment: @J.M. To be more precise, between 8.0.4 and 9.0.1 :)

Comment: @xzczd, for any other software, it would be weird to keep older versions hanging around your computer... :)

Answer (score 6):

Some insight can be gained by plotting `Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1]` in the complex plane.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ReIm[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1] /. t -> tr + I ti]], {tr, 0, Pi}, 
    {ti, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {tr, ti, f}]
```

[image]

Branch points occur at `t == n Pi`, `n` an integer, with branch cuts extending from the branch points to `t == n Pi + I ∞`.  Visibly, there also are branch cuts at `t` an odd half-integer of `Pi`, even though there are no corresponding branch points.  They are, in other words, simply an artifact of Mathematica's definition of `Sqrt[]`.  Nonetheless, they must be taken into account.

The impact of the branch cut at `t == Pi/2` is apparent from the following plot of the integrand.

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1]]], {t, 0, Pi}]
```

[image]

The real part of the integrand is symmetric, the imaginary part antisymmetric, which is consistent with the result of `NIntegrate` in the Question.  So, what does `Integrate` do as it crosses the branch cut?

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, Pi/2, Pi/2 + 10^-10}]
(* Sqrt[2] - I π + I (-Sqrt[-1 - E^(I/5000000000)] + 
   ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(I/5000000000)]]) + ArcTanh[Sqrt[2]] *)
% // N
(* 1.76275 - 3.14159 I *)
```

Evidently, integrating an infinitesimal distance produces a finite value.  Because the contour cannot be distorted around this branch cut, `Integrate` must have some built-in rule to add this value as the branch cut is crossed.  In any case, `Integrate` can be made to give the correct value by excluding the region at `t == Pi/2`.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, 0, Pi/2 - 10^-10}] + 
    Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, Pi/2 + 10^-10, Pi}]
(* I (-Sqrt[-1 - E^(-(I/5000000000))] + ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^-(I/5000000000))]]) + 
   I (Sqrt[-1 - E^(I/5000000000)] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(I/5000000000)]]) *)
% // N
(* 1.06568 + 0. I *)
```

which is the same value as obtained from `NIntegrate`, up to roundoff.

**Version 11.1.0 update.**

Version 11.1.0 returns the correct answer.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1], {t, 0, Pi}]
(* 1/2 (4 Sqrt[2] + Log[17 - 12 Sqrt[2]]) *)
% // N
(* 1.06568 *)
```

Comment: Hmm. `Limit[-I (Sqrt[-1 - E^(-2 I ε)] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(-2 I ε)]]) + I (Sqrt[-1 - E^(2 I ε)] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(2 I ε)]]), ε -> 0]` yields `2 Sqrt[2] - I Pi` in the current version, but (after simplification) `2 (Sqrt[2] - ArcSinh[1])` in 5.2.

Comment: @J.M.  Yes, I noticed the first part too.  What simplification did you use to obtain second.  I can obtain it only be setting `ε` to a very small number.

Comment: I used `FullSimplify[TrigToExp[expr]]` in 5.2 .

Comment: @J.M.  This does not work for 10.4.1, returning `expr`.  However, `Limit[expr // TrigToExp, ϵ-> 0] // FullSimplify` reproduces the second result in your first comment.  Incidentally, `Direction -> 1` flips the sign of both answers.

Comment: @J.M.  With regard to the two limits in your first comment, the first almost certainly is another bug.  In fact, because this erroneous limit is the same expression as the erroneous value from `Integrate`, it is possible that `Integrate` is somehow using this limit in its calculation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was actually hinting at with my first comment. :)

Comment: @J.M.  You are more observant than I.  Do you plan to report this to Wolfram, Inc?

Comment: I might, once I'm done with a few other things...

Answer (score 1):

`ComplexExpand` with `TargetFunctions -> Abs` help us to solve this integral.

```
f[t_] := Sqrt[Exp[I*t]^2 - 1];
complex = ComplexExpand[f[t], TargetFunctions -> Abs]
```

> `Sqrt[Abs[-1 + E^(2 I t)]]
>      Cos[1/2 (-I Log[-1 + E^(2 I t)] + I Log[Abs[-1 + E^(2 I t)]])] + 
>    I Sqrt[Abs[-1 + E^(2 I t)]]
>      Sin[1/2 (-I Log[-1 + E^(2 I t)] + I Log[Abs[-1 + E^(2 I t)]])]`

```
sol = Integrate[complex, {t, 0, Pi}]
```

> `2 (Sqrt[2] - ArcSinh[1])`

```
sol//N
```

> `1.06568`