# Symbolic and numeric limit disagreeing on branch cut of ArcTan

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, complex

**Bug introduced after 8.0.4 and before 9.0.1 and fixed in 11.1.0.**

---

Investigating comments to [my previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/116041/integrate-and-nintegrate-disagreeing-over-branch-cut-of-sqrt) lead me to the following problem:

```
 N[Limit[ ArcTan[Sqrt[-4 E^(I a)]], a -> 0]]
 (* 4.71239 + 0.549306 I *)

 Limit[N[ ArcTan[Sqrt[-4 E^(I a)]]], a -> 0]
 (* 1.5708 - 0.549306 I *)
```

In a sense, both answers are acceptable, since the square of the tangent of both of them gives -4, but they appear to disagree on the branch cut for the `ArcTan` function. Any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: v8.0.4 gives the correct answer, while v9.0.1 outputs `4.71239 + 0.549306 I` for both pieces of code. So this is bug (bugs?) introduced after v8.0.4 and partly fixed in v10.

Comment: @xzczd, just to assist debugging, what are the results of `Series[ArcTan[Sqrt[-4 E^(I a)]], {a, 0, 0}] // Normal` in all the versions you have?

Comment: @J.M. v8.0.4 and v9.0.1 gives `I ArcTanh[2] + π Floor[(π - 2 Arg[-2 I + 2 Sqrt[-E^(I a)]])/(4 π)] + π Floor[(π + 2 Arg[-2 I + 2 Sqrt[-E^(I a)]])/(4 π)]`, v10.4.1 (Wolfram Cloud) gives `I ArcTanh[
     2] + π Floor[(π - 2 Arg[-2 I + 2])/(4 π)] + π Floor[(π + 2 Arg[-2 I + 2])/(4 π)]` (Though can't be proved by `Simplify`, this seems to be the same result as that in v8 and v9.)

Comment: @bbgodfrey  `ArcTan` isn't a special function.

Comment: @Artes  I am uncertain of the definition of special function but will take you word for it that `ArcTan` does not fall in that category.  Thanks,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that

```
s = ArcTan[Sqrt[-4 E^(I a)]]
N[Limit[s, a -> 0]]
(* 4.71239 + 0.549306 I *)
```

is a bug in `Limit`.  Plotting the function `s`

```
Plot[Evaluate[ReIm[s]], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

indicates that `s` assumes the value above nowhere in the vicinity of `a == 0`.  (The same is true in the complex plane.)  Furthermore,

```
Limit[s, a -> 0]
(* π + I ArcTanh[2] *)
```

which can be transformed to

```
TrigToExp[%] // Simplify
(* 1/2 (3 π + I Log[3]) *)
```

On the other hand,

```
Limit[TrigToExp[s], a -> 0]
(* 1/2 (π - I Log[3]) *)
```

The answers should be identical but are not.

This situation is similar to the problem with `Limit` applied to `ArcTan` that was identified by [J. M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/50/j-m) in his first comment to my answer to [116041](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116053/1063).

```
expr = -I (Sqrt[-1 - E^(-2 I ε)] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(-2 I ε)]]) +
      I (Sqrt [-1 - E^(2 I ε)] - ArcTan[Sqrt[-1 - E^(2 I ε)]])
Limit[expr, ε -> 0]
(* 2 Sqrt[2] - I Pi *)

Limit[expr // TrigToExp, ϵ-> 0] // FullSimplify
(* 2 (Sqrt[2] - ArcSinh[1]) *)
```

I recommend that this be reported to Wolfram, Inc as a bug.

**Addendum**

Mathematically, the arctangent of the square root of `-4` is

```
n Pi + I ArcTanh[2]
```

or

```
n Pi - I ArcTanh[2]
```

where `n` is an arbitrary integer.  The problem exposed in the question is that `Limit[s, a -> 0]` is not choosing the same branch symbolically that `Plot`, `N`, etc. choose numerically.  This should not be.

Comment: `Limit[s, a -> 0, Direction -> 1]` does choose the same branch as `Plot` and `N`.

Comment: @Karsten7.  Good point!  So, `Limit` gets the right answer half the time. `Limit[s, a -> 0, Direction ->- 1]`, the default, should return `π - I ArcTanh[2]` instead of `π + I ArcTanh[2]` for consistency with numerical results.